# TS2554: Expected 0 arguments, but got 2

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, api, yarnpkg

Here is a modified version of the code that I have.

```
return await this.X.y(
 a,
 b,
);
```

and the function y looks like this:

```
async y(
    a: string,
    b: B,
  ) {
    return await this.foo.put(
      `${this.config.foobar}/foo/${a}`,
      b,
    );
```

and I have been getting the error stated above. How is it possible for the function to expect 0 arguments when it has 2 specified with it?

Comment: Please provide a self-contained [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing, as plain text in the body of your post. Ideally I could paste such code into a standalone IDE and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it. So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is obvious conflicts on the expected function being ran. Without no more code to see is difficult to be precise but from that example you gave, my wild guess is that either:

1. `this.foo.put()` function does really takes no arguments
2. you are thinking you are using a function but instead at runtime is another

Try to debug and get what is the prototype of `this.foo` and check again the function `put()` prototype also. I strongly think your line of thought scope is not the same of the running program, it is all about scope ;)

Comment: the second one is what it was! turns out there was a copy of the file somewhere in the code that had the function taking 0 arguments and although the compiler did not throw any errors and nor did VSCode point to that alternate copy of the function, at runtime, the function that was actually being used was the other one. Hence, the error.